# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in

Tags: function, execute, member

I am trying to insert into my table some values, but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Diploma\Clire\login-edit_file.php on line 35
```

My table is:

```
param_string, inside is idstring, fileid, key and value.
```

the code is

```
if (startsWith($key, "text_"))
            $query = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO param_string (fileid, key, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)") or die();
            $query->execute(array($file_id, $key, $value));
if (startsWith($key, "boolean_"))
            $query = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO param_string (fileid, key, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)") or die();
            $query->execute(array($file_id, $key, $value));
```

I tried searching for other problems like this but couldn't find any answers. Thank you for your help!